# "Illegal scheme supplied, only alphanumeric characters are permitted" Magento

Tags: php, magento

After about 2 years the site suddenly throws this error without any code changes (also when surfing to ../admin).

**Also another magento site on the same webspace, has the same exact problem.**

Other solutions presented for this problem are about a malformated base_url variable, however this is not the case here. Also because it worked all the time, this shouldn't be the problem.

Could it be that there is a kind of overload or failure to connect to the database?

Answer (score 2):

To solve this error, primary things we should check first:

Check 'web/unsecure/base_url' and 'web/secure/base_url' entries in the table 'core_config_data' and make sure URL should not contain any white space & correct URL should be there
We should check the database connection string located under 'app/etc/local.xml' and make sure database, username & password should not contain illegal characters like '[' which can break the XML.

Comment: Thank you but this cannot be the issue, because nothing was changed to the site and it was running for over 2 years now until a week ago when this error appeared.

Comment: This was the problem exactly can`t say how much time you saved me. Had to dig my SA password out of a pile of notes to leave the TOS breaking comment ; ) cheers

Comment: Just want to say I was having this issue when creating credit memos using the Authorize.net payment option and I had some whitespace before the URL in the Gateway url in the config. Removing it fixed the issue so thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The *Illegal Scheme* exception comes from

```
#File: lib/Zend/Uri.php
public static function factory($uri = 'http', $className = null)
{
    //...
    if (ctype_alnum($scheme) === false) {
        #require_once 'Zend/Uri/Exception.php';
        throw new Zend_Uri_Exception('Illegal scheme supplied, only alphanumeric characters are permitted');
    }
```

Which means somewhere in your system, probably due to a value set in `System -> Configuration`, there's a URL with a non alpha numeric character set.

You can identify the bad string by adding some temporary logging to the system

```
public static function factory($uri = 'http', $className = null)
{
    Mage::Log($uri);
    file_put_contents('/tmp/uri.log',"\n",FILE_APPEND);
```

And then fixing the value (probably in the `core_config_data` table)

[See also](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/26158/illegal-scheme-supplied-only-alphanumeric-characters-are-permitted).

Comment: Thank you but this cannot be the issue, because nothing was changed to the site and it was running for over 2 years now until a week ago when this error appeared.

Comment: @nauti At least you can try to debug using the code snippet given by Alan.

Comment: @nauti Well, if the site was working, and now isn't working, then it seems more likely that your assumption nothing's been changed is incorrect.  There may be more happening with your site than you think.  (host changing PHP versions, an extension bug causing a problem, etc.)